# Примеры LoadingObjectManager или RemoteObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Окончательно запутался. Необходимо отрисовывать большое количество кругов. Хочу использовать ROM или  LOM. Загвоздка в понимании (точнее непонимании) как динамичкски создавать тайлы (как вообще их создавать).  [В этом примере](https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-examples/tree/ru-v2.1/hotspot_layer/hotspot_data/10) тайлы в виде готовых файлов. И непонятно как они были созданы. Не могу найти внятных примеров. Собственно вопрос: как динамически создать тайлы на сервере и как их загрузить на клиента.

Comment: Если вы не знаете зачем вам ROM или LOM то может просто использовать OM как в примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_spatial ? Почему вы решили, что вам нужен ROM или LOM ?

Comment: Уже сделал с использованием ОМ. Ну, 600 объектов отрисовываются нормально. Но предполагаю, что объектов может быть в разы больше. На 20000 полигонах OM тормозил прилично.

Comment: "На 20000 полигонах OM тормозил прилично." тогда нужно будет добавить ROM и кластеризацию.

Comment: Вот! Все уперлось в создание тайлов. Не могу догнать, как их создать. Причем динамически (не известно, какая область будет загружена).

Comment: Посмотрите на эту реализацию https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/tree/master/remote-object-manager-server

Comment: Не нашел в этом примере работы с тайлами. Как и с ROM.

Comment: Ну собственно это уже готовый сервер для ROM, ему осталось только подсунуть данные.

Comment: Не получается его стартануть((( node server.js     ругань на at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'    ....и тишина. Модуль bson поставил на всякий случай, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84648/discussion-between-se0ga-and-cold-pol).